# adding a unique index id for the stacked rows in r

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to add a unique index id variable for the same id rows. Here is a snapshot of my dataset.

```
id <- c(1234, 1234, 2241,2241, 1252,1252,1252)
step <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,-1)

data <- data.frame(id, step)

> data
    id step
1 1234    0
2 1234    0
3 2241    0
4 2241    0
5 1252    0
6 1252    1
7 1252   -1
```

so with the unique index id should look like this:

```
> data
    id step  index
1 1234    0   1
2 1234    0   1
3 2241    0   2
4 2241    0   2
5 1252    0   3
6 1252    1   3
7 1252   -1   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` from `base R`

```
data$index <- with(data, match(id, unique(id)))
data$index
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `base` solution:

```r
transform(data, index=as.numeric(factor(id, levels = unique(id))))

#     id step index
# 1 1234    0     1
# 2 1234    0     1
# 3 2241    0     2
# 4 2241    0     2
# 5 1252    0     3
# 6 1252    1     3
# 7 1252   -1     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, index := .GRP, by = id]

data
#         id step index
#    1: 1234    0     1
#    2: 1234    0     1
#    3: 2241    0     2
#    4: 2241    0     2
#    5: 1252    0     3
#    6: 1252    1     3
#    7: 1252   -1     3
```